# Principal is null when CSRF disabled

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, csrf, spring-oauth2

I'm creating a webapp that uses `spring-boot-starter-security` and `spring-security-oauth2` to use Facebook for login.

To avoid implementing all that CSRF-stuff in angular 2 (and because it's just a toy project) I want to turn off CSRF.
I have implemented the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

But now the `Principal`-Object is always `null`:

```
Task createTask(@RequestBody Task task, Principal principal) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Why?
I guess I unintentionally overwrite the security config configured in my application.yaml, but even if I add an `Order`-Annotation it doesn't work :(

**Edit:**
Request headers (I created a Filter to add a XSRF-TOKEN cookie, ignore that):

```
POST /foo HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:81
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 15
Origin: http://localhost:81
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:81/create-task
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.681162454.1458756836; JSESSIONID=F65FB28C14A8A2D870D18842DE855212; XSRF-TOKEN=551858ab-678e-4dcb-bc72-44fbc569ec41
```

Comment: Does the angular application address (in the browser url bar) matches the host and port where the spring application listens?

Comment: Yes. If I delete the config everything works as expected (except for POST, PUT etc which are forbidden bc of CSRF)

Comment: Can  you take a look at chrome network panel or a debugging proxy (i.e Fiddler) and show what the angular ajax request headers look like?